# Were Kohanim in the Temple obligated in Torah reading?

Tags: halacha-theory, synagogue, beis-hamikdash, torah-reading

Following "[synagogue-in-the-temple](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108827/what-is-meant-by-synagogue-in-the-temple)",

In the times of the Second Temple, assuming that not all Kohanim were involved in Temple Service all the time:

Were they obligated in Torah reading and was Torah read regularly? if Yes, where did the reading take place and where were the Torah scrolls kept?

Comment: Mishnah Tamid 5:1

Comment: @Alex Thank you, I took this part out, because I remembered Teffilot came after the destruction.